# Best way to handle useRef(null) in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I've got this `titleRef`

```
const titleRef = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement | null>(null);
```

It's attached to this header:

```
<h1 ref={titleRef}>Hi!</h1>
```

I want to use it to do some work with styling on screen resize, like so:

```
if (titleRef.current.style.offsetWidth > '10px') {...}
```

TS doesn't like this. See, `useRef(null)` means that titleRef *could* equal `null` (which, fair enough) and so everywhere I use `titleRef`, I have to account for that with something like

```
if (titleRef.current) {
  ...do the thing
}`
```

which gets to be a pain in the ass if `titleRef` gets used a lot.

Is there more elegant way to handle this situation? Directly set `titleRef` to be the `<h1>` element directly in `useRef`? Or, instead of using `null`, pass `useRef()` some "generic" `HTMLHeadingElement`?

Edit: Optional chaining was the the first thing I tried, but, that doesn't appear to help:

[image: the linter still throws an error]

Edit 2: adding an `!` does clear the warning, but it also makes the value static and might lead to trouble, depending on your use case.

Edit 3: using optional chaining can also make the linter mad, if you're going modify `titleRef.current`.

[image: no optional left hand assignment]

If you're not modifying the value, only reading it, then `?` should be fine, but if not...

### TL;DR

While the answers below work *some* of the time, the downsides don't seem worth it, to me. For now, I'm going to stick to my if spam...

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Optional chaiining? `titleRef.current?.style.offsetWidth`

Comment: Or, explicitly telling that you know it's not null `titleRef.current!.style.offsetWidth`

Comment: In your case, I'd go with what @Nishant suggested above (the optional chaining, not the `!`)

Comment: I don't think optional chaining works, @Nishant (though I might have something misconfigured). See screenshot above. The `!` does clear the warning, but I'm not certain the implications of using it. Not clear to me exactly when the ref becomes not null.

Answer (score 7):

If you are not going to assign `null` in the future and it is just an initial value, then you can use :

```
const titleRef = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null!);
```

The  exclamation mark after `null` tells typescript that it is meant to be initial value and the value will most possibly change.

Check out Typescript-cheatsheets notes [here](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#useref)

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly what I was looking for, with one caveat: it will make the ref immutable. 

For my purposes, that's okay, but it might cause issues for others...

Comment: The problem with not-null assertion that you run into the risk of run time failure. See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-typescript-forked-wmolp?file=/src/index.tsx  (it crashes on click) It has similar effect as `myTestRef.current!.focus()` so be warned.

Comment: Maybe I'll stick to my if bloat.

Comment: You may need to check your tsc setting, ideally optional chaining is meant to handle such bloat without causing a run time error.

Comment: [Seems you're probably right](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/chaining/) @Nishant. I'll continue investigating.

Comment: "Note that ref.current may be null. This is expected, because you may conditionally render the ref-ed element, or you may forget to assign it".  In other words, you can use the `null!` hack if (1) you don't conditionally render the ref-ed element, (2) you correctly remembered to assign the ref, and (3) you access the ref where you know the view has been rendered (i.e. in a useEffect or in an event handler).  And for example, you could conditionally render a button but access `ref.current` inside its onClick where you know it won't be null.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I ended up testing this. Optional chaining can help you get rid of the `if` that's bloating your code:

```ts
  const myTestRef = React.useRef<IFancyRef>(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    myTestRef.current?.focus();
    // or
    myTestRef.current!.focus(); // this assumes you KNOW that myTestRef is assigned
  };
```

[Here Codesandbox for you](https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-typescript-forked-yng5c?file=/src/index.tsx:167-317)